# Flask HTML Extend printing "{% extends %}" instead of extending

Tags: python, html, flask

My webpage just prints out "{% extends 'base.html'% }". I'm wanting it to just print out the header "Template".[image]

Both html files are in templates and the py file is one directory outside of that.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Template</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks like it didn't use `Jinja2` to generate HTML but it is strange because `flask` should have installed and configured `Jinja2` from the beginning.

Comment: Jinja2 is already installed.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong or off with the code, it should have worked.

Comment: as I said - it is strange because Jinja2 is installed with `flask`, code looks ok, it doesn't display any error message on page. The only idea it uses other rendering engine but I don't know why and where to change engine.

Comment: I see only one explanation - you clicked on `index.html` and you opened it as normal file. But you have to run code and it should display information with url - ie. `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` - and you should use `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` in web browser.

Comment: So I was running this from an atom pseudo-terminal (hit a hotkey and it runs it and outputs as if it were a terminal but no interaction otherwise). Seems that it may have interfered with the parsing of html. Running directly from windows cmd worked perfectly.